# FedEx Freight API Error: "Account and meter number aren't consistent"

Tags: php, api, fedex

Using the downloadable SDK/API for FedEx Freight I plugged in the numbers given to me in my welcome email - Example of my email:

> Test Password: *password*
>
> Test Account Number:510xxxxxx (for FedEx Web Services for Shipping only)
>
> Test Meter Number:118xxxxxx (for FedEx Web Services for Shipping only)
>
> FedEx Freight LTL Shipper
>     Account Number: xxxxxx123
>
> FedEx Freight LTL Bill To/Third Party
>     Account Number: xxxxxx234

I've replaced the values in the getProperty() function as below:

```
if($var == 'shipaccount') Return 'xxxxxx123';
if($var == 'billaccount') Return 'xxxxxx123';
if($var == 'accounttovalidate') Return 'FedExAccount#';
if($var == 'meter') Return '118xxxxxx';
if($var == 'key') Return 'apiKey';
if($var == 'account') Return 'FedExAccount#';
if($var == 'freightaccount') Return 'xxxxxx234';
if($var == 'password') Return '*password*';
```

If I change any of the account numbers around (I've tried multiple variations in case I'm doing it wrong) I get either an authentication error or:

> All specified account numbers must match.

Otherwise, when everything seems to match up fine, I get the all pervasive:

> "Account and meter number aren't consistent"

Am I doing something wrong here?  I can't find anything in the documentation that answers this, and searching for the error in google isn't helping me find a solution.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: There isn't a "email support" and calling (and waiting on hold) isn't my thing if I can solve it easily in other ways. Email option only puts you in queue to talk to a representative and none of the options has anything to do with development.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this error also comes up if the postal code doesn't match the account.

Were these credentials setup on the test server? From time to time the data gets purged and needs to be re-submitted.

You can call the FedEx support # and ask for "web services" or email websupport@fedex.com - the folks there are very helpful.